# Build error MSB600 "tsc.exe" exited with code 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, typescript

Can anyone give any insight. Couldn't find any information about this.
-Asp.net 5 project-        Visual studio 2015
Encountered the below error

> Error MSB6006 "tsc.exe" exited with code 2. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets   213

EDIT:
This is line 213 of the Microsoft.TypeScript.targets file

```
  <VsTsc
  ToolPath="$(TscToolPath)"
  ToolExe="$(TscToolExe)"
  TSConfigFile="%(ConfigFiles.Identity)"
  YieldDuringToolExecution="$(TscYieldDuringToolExecution)"
  ProjectDir="$(ProjectDir)"
  ToolsVersion="$(TypeScriptToolsVersion)"
  TypeScriptCompileBlocked="$(TypeScriptCompileBlocked)"
  ComputeOutputOnly="false">
```

I have succeded to compile with gulp-typescript library.

> [16:27:47] Starting 'build-ts'... Process terminated with code 0.
>
> [16:27:50] TypeScript: 4 semantic errors.
>
> [16:27:50] TypeScript: emit succeeded (with errors)
>
> [16:27:50] Finished 'build-ts' after 3.49 s

Comment: i removed  "pretty": true from tsconfig.json file and now it doesnt throw this error

Comment: I am also getting this same error. could not figure out what is the actual cause of this problem. If anyone can help.

Answer (score 14):

There may be multiple reasons behind this error. The problem is VS does not show exact error returned by TypeScript compiler.

I wrote a blog post that explains small trick to get detailed error message, I hope it will be useful for someone: http://the-coderok.azurewebsites.net/2016/07/13/Resolve-the-Error-MSB6006-tsc-exe-exited-with-code-2-build-error-in-Visual-Studio-2015/

Comment: It was a big help! Thanks!

Comment: My problem was with the rendertron package.  After I followed the steps on the blog to see the detail, I was able to see the root cause of the problem and got rid of that package.  Or at least will find another way to implement it to the project.

Answer (score 12):

If you are having problems with ASP.NET Core xproj compilation and don't have any .ts file, you could disable Typescript compilation modifying .xproj file and adding:

```
<TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
```

Inside the first

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
    ...
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 7):

After updating TypescriptToolsVersion to 1.8

```html
 <TypeScriptToolsVersion>1.8</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```

Change Typescript Targets paths to include TypeScriptionVersion location. like below.

```html
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\$(TypeScriptToolsVersion)\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\$(TypeScriptToolsVersion)\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Changing my tsconfig.json fixed that for me.
it looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "wwwroot/app/",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  },
  "filesGlob": [
    "node_modules/**",
    "wwwroot/**/*",
    "typings/**/*"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": false
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer was that I had a project that was using TypeScript 2.0 with Visual Studio 2015 that I opened in Visual Studio 2013. Opening it in Visual Studio 2015 fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and seeing you fixed yours by your comment on your question by removing the bad tsconfig.json lead me to find the cause of my error too.

I had this line in my tsconfig.json in efforts to get my sourcemap files to work with my browser again.

```
"sourceRoot": "/"
```

Removing this line fixed the issue (and hadn't been fixing my sourcemap issue it transpired anyway)

I guess if you're hitting this issue you have a bad tsconfig.json `compilerOptions`

Answer (score 0):

My app would compile fine on my machine, but fail when building in Azure DevOps. I fixed it by changing TypeScriptToolsVersion in my csproj file...

```
<TypeScriptToolsVersion>Latest</TypeScriptToolsVersion>
```